spread() is giving unexpected results: it is filling an entire column with 0 (tidyr)
I have a df with 1x10^7 obs and 3 variables that looks like this:
         sp_id              sample       reads
         <char>             <char>       <int>
       1: sp1               sample1       255
       2: sp1               sample2       1
       3: sp1               sample3       1152
       4: sp2               sample1       114
       5: sp2               sample2       3
         ----               ----          ---
       10000000:  sp42500   sample6700    4554
 

In total I have 6700 different samples and 42500 species.
I would like to spread the data, so each sample is a column and the reads are the values. The missing values would be filled with 0.
I used:
data <- df %>% spread(key=sample, value=nreads, fill=0)
My expected result would be:
         sp_id              sample1       sample2      sample3    ...  sample 6700
         <char>             <int>          <int>        <int>            <int> 
       1: sp1               255              1           1152            561
       2: sp2               114              3           0                3
          ----               ----          ---         ----             ----
       42500: sp42500        715             0           0               4554

The problem
Is that after the 24th column, it is filling everything with 0, as if those samples did not have any species observations (which is not true)
         sp_id              sample24       sample25      sample26    ...  sample 6700
         <char>             <int>          <int>        <int>            <int> 
       1: sp1               45              0              0                0
       2: sp2               3               0              0                0
          ----               ----          ---         ----             ----
       42500: sp42500        715             0           0                 0

I have also tried other functions that have given me other errors:
> data <- df %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = sample, values_from = reads, values_fill=0)
Error in `vec_rep_each()`:! `times` can't be missing. Location 1 is missing.Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.Warning message:In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow

> data <- dcast(setDT(df), sp_id ~ sample, value.var = "reads", fill=0)
Error: Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 2853905958 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647

Thank you everyone!
UPDATE
It has worked correctly when I divided the df into two parts:
df1 <- df[c(1:5000000),]
df2 <- df[-c(1:5000000),]

data1 <- df1 %>% spread(key=sample, value=nreads, fill=0)
data2 <- df2 %>% spread(key=sample, value=nreads, fill=0)

data <- bind_rows(data1,data2)


Hard to tell withouth having the full data set, but it looks like your original data has no rows where sp_id %in% c('sp1', 'sp2') and sample == 'sample25'.
Try df %>% filter(sample == 'sample25')  to see what sp_id`s you have.

Hi Cett, thank you for you answer. I have checked and I have several species observations (reads) in sample_25, as well as in all the other samples. It has only worked correctly when I have split the original df into two parts, spread them separately and then bind_rows() them.
